# How do I configure an image field with Url Options?

Tags: glass-mapper

If I were mapping a `Link` type field, I can override the default URL options like this.

```
[SitecoreField(UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl)]
public Link ThisIsALink { get; set; }
```

If I were using fluent configuration, it would look like this.

```
Map(x =>
{
    x.Field(field => field.ThisIsALink)
     .Configuration.UrlOptions = SitecoreInfoUrlOptions.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl;
});
```

How can I do the same with an `Image` type field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like is a know issue https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/111 ;
I suggest you to open an issue ticket on GlassMapper github;

https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues

Maybe @MichaelEdwars will fix it in future versions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue unfortunately. I just needed the image URL so had to go down the route of implementing an extension method.
Something like below

```
public static string GetAbsoluteUrl(this Image value, ISitecoreContext sitecoreContext = null)
{
    if (value == null || value.MediaId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var mediaItem = (sitecoreContext ?? new SitecoreContext()).Database.GetItem(new ID(value.MediaId));
    if (mediaItem == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    var options = MediaUrlOptions.Empty;
    options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
    return MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(new MediaItem(mediaItem), options);
}
```